# Categorical sum of maps

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, category-theory

I was reading that the product and the sum of two open maps are again open (and the sum of closed maps is closed too). Since the product of ${\rm id} : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ with itself is not open, I assume that "product" and "sum" above are used in some categorical sense, i.e. the "product" must be the Cartesian product of maps. What , then, about the sum of two maps? How is it defined? Is it related to the disjoint union of sets? I have never encountered this term before.

Edit:

If $f : X \to X'$ and $g: Y \to Y'$, I assume that the sum is $f \coprod g : X \coprod Y \to X' \coprod Y'$, defined by... Ok, it's complicated to write its definition, I guess that for elements in $X$ it behaves like $f$ and for elements in $Y$ it behaves like $g$. I'd just like a confirmation of my intuition.

Comment: Is it possible that is it simply $(f*g)(x) = f(x) * g(x)$...? Because $x \mapsto x^2$ is indeed not an open map. Edit: I think maybe I misunderstood what you wanted. Yes, if $f : X \to Y$ and $g : X' \to Y'$, there is a map $f \sqcup g : X \sqcup X' \to Y \sqcup Y'$ called the sum of $f$ and $g$, and similarly for the product. It's defined via the universal properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sum often refers to the coproduct, which is the disjoint union with the obvious topology (see below) in the case of the category of topological spaces. If $f : X \to X'$, $g : Y \to Y'$ are maps, then $f \sqcup g : X \sqcup Y \to X' \sqcup Y'$ is simply defined by $x \mapsto f(x)$ on $X$ and $y \mapsto g(y)$ on $Y$. If $f,g$ are open, then $f \sqcup g$ is open, because the open subsets of $X \sqcup Y$ are $U \sqcup V$ for open subsets $U \subseteq X$, $V \subseteq Y$, and the image of this set is $f(U) \sqcup g(V)$, thus open in $X' \sqcup Y'$. The same proof works for closed maps.